# Why generic nvidia card(like gtx1080) can't virtualize?

Tags: gpu, virtualization, nvidia

I read only grid 1.0 and 2.0 products can virtualize.

I read this product share cuda and dedicate framebuffer.

Is it not possible generic nvidia card virtualize like grid product only using software method(iommu, vfio-pci, ovmf, mmu ...) ?

Or any project exist?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like marketing stuff. You need to pay a LOT of money to use "professional" adapters like GRID. AFAIK, you even need to pay for virtual video drivers that will be installed on your virtual machine. So you can't do virtualization with generic videocard just because nvidia needs a little bit more of money.

Unfortunately no projects exists that allows us to use consumer videocard in virtualization. The only thing you can do with generic card is to passthroug it completely to one of virtual machines.